# NativeScript RadListView UI not showing inside TabViewItem

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have create a app with a **TabView** inside my **TabViewItem** i have two **ListView** and two **RadListView** but unfortunately *RadListView* not Display any data or neither an error. I am using latest version NativeScript Core and **nativescript-ui-listview@6.1.0**

[Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=XOTi92)

I already try to install old version **nativescript-ui-listview** but it don't work for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific, which platform you are facing the issue with? Which Tab is not loading? At least on my end I see all tabs loading as expected with Android 8.0.

Comment: In my android 5.1.1 device. I am also try in Genymotion Android Emulator 7.1.x same issue. The problem in my **Categories** & **Portals** TabViewItems

Comment: I can also see all the tabs(including Categories & Portals ) on ios.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with `RadListView`, it doesn't seem to work right after you load a `ListView`. If you scroll fast enough to reach categories / portal tab before your ListViews (from news / trending tabs) are loaded, it works not otherwise. You might want to report the same at [Gtihub](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues). May be you could replace all your ListView with RadListView as a workaround.